# Product of limits of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers.

Let  $$s_n = \frac{x_1 + \ ... \ + x_n}{n}$$

$$t_n = \frac {\frac{1}{x_1} + \ ... \ + \frac{1}{x_n}}{n}$$

Prove that if $s_n \to S$ and $\ t_n \to T, \ ST \geqslant 1$

A hint in the text says to use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\big(\sum_{r=1}^n\sqrt{x_r}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_r}}\big)^2\le \sum_{r=1}^n{\sqrt{x_r}}^2\cdot\sum_{r=1}^n\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_r}}\big)^2$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{r=1}^n{x_r}\cdot\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{{x_r}}\ge n^2$$

Also, 
$$s_n\cdot t_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{r=1}^n{x_r}\cdot\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{{x_r}}\ge 1$$

Comment: Isn't the LHS of the first inequality supposed to be squared? (Otherwise it evaluates to $n$, not $n^2$.)

Comment: That was a typo. I intended to use Cauchy shwarz inequality.